# What is the best way to react to ngxs state changes within your component for loading or error events?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngxs

I have a PostListComponent which iterates over all of the posts retrieved from the server and displays individual PostItemComponent. I am using NGXS for state management. When I initiate the fetchPosts requests, I change the state property loading: true. When request finishes successfully I change it back to false. If a request fails I update the error object on the state and update the error object message property and exception property.

Here is what I have so far

```
`
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {    
  private posts$: Observable<any> = this.store.select(state => state.posts);
  private isLoading: boolean = false;
  private error: object = {};

  constructor(
    public postsFacade: PostsFacadeService,
    public moviesFacade: MoviesFacadeService,
    private store: Store) {    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts$.subscribe(
      (state) => this.onLoadingEvent(state)
      );

    this.posts$.subscribe(
      (error) => this.onErrorEvent(error)
    )
    // this.posts$.pipe(
    //   mergeMap(() => {
    //     // perform the subscription here and listen for state changes
    //   })
    // )

  }

  onErrorEvent(error)
  {
    this.error = error.error;
  }

  onLoadingEvent(state)
  {
    this.isLoading = state.loading;  
  }
`
```

Structure of my store

```
`
@State<PostStateModel>({
    name: 'posts',
    defaults: {
        posts: [],
        loading: false,
        error: {
          message: "",
          error: ""                   
        },
    }
})
`
```

I feel like there is a better way of subscribing to state changes within the store with using perhaps the rxjs mergeMap operator. I am not sure if that is possible and if the current approach is efficient. How else can i subscribe to and react to store changes from within my component?

Answer (score 0):

So a few things:

1. You need define some state actions for your state class - LoadPosts for example.
2. You should dispatch that action (say in your ngOnInit), or somewhere prior to the component loading. The action should call the services that actually fetch the data, thereby removing this dependency from your component.
3. If the service uses Observables or Promises you should handle when they finally return by updating your state at that point.
4. You can create your observable via @Select. Notice that this way it is typed.

   @Select(PostState) postState$: Observable;
5. You can use the async pipe in your component and you may not need to subscribe to the postState$ directly in your code (e.g. to use *ngFor to iterate thru the posts).
6. Because your state includes the posts, the loading flag and the error, subscribing to the state as a whole will cause your subscription function or async pipe to be run no matter which of these changes.  If you create selector methods with @Selector() in your state class, you can subscribe to these for finer granularity for example to only react to the loading flag.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be pretty heavy and includes setting up an interceptor for your application. Then errors will bubble up to it.

[ngxs.io/advanced/errors](https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/errors)

If you're not up to building that full-cycle setup you can do a lightweight version by informing a response status "slice" `resStatus`.

```
export interface IReqStatus {
  loading?: boolean;
  error?: any;
  success?: boolean;
  action?: string; <-- optionally send along the action this belongs to
}
```

Example action making a request to an API endpoint

```
@Action(UpdateSomething)
updateSomething(ctx: StateContext<SomeStateModel>, { payload }: any): any {

   // 1. update the resStatus to show "busy"
  ctx.dispatch(new UpdateResStatus({ loading: true, action: 'updateSomething' }));

  return this.apiService.patch('/something/endpoint', payload).pipe(
    tap((res) => {
      // 2. update resStatus to show success
      ctx.dispatch(new UpdateResStatus(res));
    }),

    // 3. update the resStatus with errors
    catchError((err: any) => {
      return ctx.dispatch(new UpdateResStatus(err));
    })
  );
}
```

Use an Action to manage the response status

```
@Action(UpdateResStatus)
updateResStatus(ctx: StateContext<SomeStateModel>, { payload }: any): Observable<any> {
  let status = {
    loading: false,
    success: payload?.status == 'success',
    error: payload?.status == 'success',
    ...(payload?.action && { action: payload?.action }),
  };
  ctx.setState(patch<SomeStateModel>({ reqStatus: status }));
  return of(payload);
}
```

In my case the server responds with a success status property.
But if the request is completely broken the catchError should update the `reqStatus`.

You can watch your request statuses with `state.reqStatus` anywhere. And hopefully you can even keep your `async pipe`'s in tact like:

```
<button [loading]="$any(reqStatus$ | async).loading" ...>
```